# Jquery-ui autocomplete selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to get selected item object like this.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete('selected').val();
```

But i don't know how can i get the selected object.

**I don't want to use autocomplete select function.**

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select:function(){}//I don't want use this.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Simply write and getting the selected value
$("#tags").val()
//Jsfiddle demo
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dintal/8eb0fopf/9/#&togetherjs=1rePhrjBBM